# Exception while adding TimeScaleValue MS Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-office, ms-project

I'm getting this exception in this code:

```
Dim TSV As TimeScaleValues
TSV = ActiveProject.Task(ntask).Resources(nresource).TimeScaleData(nStartDate , nEndDate, PjResourceTimescaledData.pjResourceTimescaledActualWork, PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleDays, 1)

TSV.item(1).Add( nMinutes , 1 ) ' nMinutes is the value of time in minutes. The error occours in this line !!!!
```

When I execute the last line I get this exception

> Invalid value for argument.
>
> > Error code -2146827187
> >
> > {Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.TimeScaleValue Add(System.Object, System.Object)}

The estrange thing is that I got this example right from this [microsoft reference page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/office.vbapj.chm131340%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

What I'm trying to do is add a time to time scale on project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I was setting the value in the wrong place.

Seems confuse, but I was trying to get the time scale value from resource, but the right place to set the values is on assignments.

I was doing this..

```
TSV = ActiveProject.Task(ntask).Resources(nresource).TimeScaleData...
```

The right code is like:

```
TSV = ActiveProject.Assignments.TimeScaleData..
```

For each resource in the task is created one assingment, so teh final code is like:

```
 For Each assignment As Assignment In Task.Assigments
     if assignment.Resource.WindowsUserAccount = <desiredAccount> then
         tsv = assingment.TimeScaleData..
   end if
Next
```